# How can you pass an object from the form_for helper to a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So let's say I have a form which is being sent somewhere strange (and by strange we mean, NOT the default route:

```
<% form_for @form_object, :url => {:controller => 'application',
                  :action => 'form_action_thing'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

Now let's say that we have the method that accepts it.

```
def form_action_thing
  User.find(????? :email ?????)
end
```

My questions are thus:

1. How can I make the object `@form_object` available to the receiving method (in this case, `form_action_tag`)?

   - I've tried `params[:form_object]`, and I've scoured [this site](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) and the API, which I have to post below because SO doesn't believe I'm not a spammer (I'm a new member), as well as Googled as many permutations of this idea as I could think of. Nothing. Sorry if I missed something, i'm really trying.
2. How do I address the object, once I've made it accessible to the method? Not `params[:form_object]`, I'm guessing.

## EDIT

Thanks so much for the responses, guys! I really appreciate it. I learned my lesson, which is that you shouldn't deep-copy an object from a form, and that the parameters of a form are actually included when you submit it.

I will admit it's sort of disheartening to not know stuff that seems so obvious though...

Comment: This is that other site I looked at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how do you set up your routes. If you're using the default /:controller/:action/:id route, you can pass it as a parameter in the URL. Note that not the whole @form_object can/should be passed, but it's id or some other attribute to identify it instead. In this case, you should make your URL:

```
<% form_for @form_object, :url => {:controller => 'application',
                  :action => 'form_action_thing', :email => some_email} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller

```
def form_action_thing
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
end
```

Comment: If you're defining email input field, you don't have to define it as parameter in `:url`.

Comment: Ah, I see, many thanks indeed. Sometimes it makes me feel silly that I don't know these things. Given the simplicity of your answer, it seems like I could have found it myself. May I ask where you would have looked?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the `f.text_field :email` param. Which makes me ask: why would you need to find by email in the controller if you are sending it, presumably, to edit or create a FormObject?

You can find more info about form helpers in the Rails guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects). If you are new into Rails this guide is pretty much recommended :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the "id" of your "@form_object" in the url and then lookup that object (assuming you have a model and using ActiveRecord)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but the @form_object is empty at that point. What I really needed to know, it seems was how to pass parameters, which I just found out.

Comment: @form_object cano not be empty, the form won't generate that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters through the url, but when submitting a form the only thing that should (probably) be passed through the url is the record id for a RESTful record.

And it appears you didn't find out yet where your form data can be found in the `params`.

So

- All the data from your form should end up in `params[:form_object]`. The actual value for `:form_object` is selected by Rails, it's probably coming from the object's class (too lazy to look that up right now)
- In any case, you can easily find out where your form values are submitted by looking at your console/log output. All the params for each requests are dumped there.
- The form fields will be inside the params like `params[:form_object][:email]` - each field that is submitted has an entry corresponding to the field name.
- The `params` hash **not** contain all the original values from your `@form_object`. There will be only those values that you included in the form.
- If you need to pass non-editable values to the controller with your form, use `hidden_field`(s) These will be submitted with the form, but are not visible to the user.